# Convert a dataframe to json?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample dataframe defined like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["167517", "TOCOTOCO25k","122.31"], ["167517", "PHUCLONG30","100.5"],["87691","TAITHU","150"]],
    index=["1", "2","3"],
    columns=["user_id", "voucher_code","scoring"],
)
```

Which looks like this:

```
    user_id voucher_code scoring
1   167517  TOCOTOCO25k  122.31
2   167517  PHUCLONG30   100.5
3   87691   TAITHU       150
```

When I use `df.json()` the output look like this:

```
{
   "user_id":{
      "1":"167517",
      "2":"167517",
      "3":"87691"
   },
   "voucher_code":{
      "1":"TOCOTOCO25k",
      "2":"PHUCLONG30",
      "3":"TAITHU"
   },
   "scoring":{
      "1":"122.31",
      "2":"100.5",
      "3":"150"
   }
}
```

But I want to like this. how can I convert dataframe to this format?

```
  [
        {
          "user_id": "167517",
          "vouchers": [
            {
              "voucher_code": "PHUCLONG30",
              "scoring": "122.31"
            },
            {
              "voucher_code": "TOCOTOCO",
              "scoring": "100"
            }
          ]
        },
    {
          "user_id": "87691",
          "vouchers": [
            {
              "voucher_code": "TAITHU",
              "scoring": "150"
            }
          ]
        }
    ]
```

I know this is simple but I don't know how I convert this JSON formate. thank you

Comment: By "parse" you mean "convert"? Then try `df.to_json()`

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to convert to thats json format using df.to_json()

Comment: Please add the correct expected output.The `df` and the `json` are not same. See the third row

Comment: @Junkrat oh sorry my bad, updated 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try group dataframe by user_id and map grouped results to needed structure:

```
import json

grouped = df.groupby('user_id').agg({"voucher_code": lambda x: list(x), "scoring": lambda x: list(x) })
result = []
for t in grouped.itertuples():
  result.append({'user_id': t.Index, 'vouchers': [{'voucher': v, 'scoring': s} for v,s in zip(t.voucher_code, t.scoring)]})

json.dumps(r)
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "167517",
        "vouchers": [
            {
                "voucher": "TOCOTOCO25k",
                "scoring": "122.31"
            },
            {
                "voucher": "PHUCLONG30",
                "scoring": "100.5"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "user_id": "87691",
        "vouchers": [
            {
                "voucher": "TAITHU",
                "scoring": "150"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```